# Dismiss Firefox certificate warnings on a subdomain and apply for other subdomains under same parent

Tags: firefox, ssl-certificate

Firefox prompts to accept a certificate separately for each subdomain. Is there a way to tell it not to?

For example, if the user visits aardvark.example.com and accepts the certificate, then to bluejay.example.com it should not ask again, even if the certificate is not the same (not a *.example.com, and same behavior even if it is).

Would there also be a way to export and import these exception rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not, unfortunately, a way to whitelist a whole domain. Exceptions are done on a per-domain basis, even when the certificate is explicitly good for *.example.com.

The exceptions file is in your [profile directory](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data); it's called `cert_override.txt`. I've had success copying it between profiles.

Comment: copy the file helps! dont mind adding seperately on to that